# protractor double click in a specific location

Tags: angularjs, mouse, double-click, angularjs-e2e, protractor

I'm developing a system (with AngularJS) that has a feature that is invoked by double clicking in a place on a web page and then I get the coordinates of the mouse and do what I want.

I'm trying to do e2e testing using protractor and I can't find any information on how to simulate the double click and get the location back.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
browser.actions().doubleClick(myElement).perform()
```

Answer (score 16):

You can do this with a WebDriver ActionSequence, but you have to tell it where to click instead of getting the location back:

`browser.actions().mouseMove({x: 50, y: 50}).doubleClick().perform()`

Answer (score 0):

**You should be able to do a test the same way you would test ng-click, just twice**

```
it('should check ng-click', function() {
   expect(binding('count')).toBe('0');
   element('.doc-example-live :button').click();
   element('.doc-example-live :button').click();
   expect(binding('count')).toBe('1');
 });
```

Comment: I need to get the location of the clicks and not the element that was clicked.

Comment: Wouldn't the verification be simply getting the coordinates of the elements and comparing it against the results that you've gotten?

Comment: Remember element.click returns a Promise.